# Javascript - How to make sliding puzzle pieces slide rather than jump into place.

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

'I'm working on a 3x3 sliding-tile puzzle game using Javascript.

Currently everything is working correctly, except I would like to make the tiles slide into position, rather than jump into place - which is what the current code is doing.

This is the current code that relates to moving the tiles:

```
document.getElementById('puzzle').onclick = function() {
  if (distance(clickLoc.x, clickLoc.y, emptyLoc.x, emptyLoc.y) == 1) {
    slideTile(emptyLoc, clickLoc);
    drawTiles();

function slideTile(toLoc, fromLoc) {
  if (!solved) {
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].x = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x;
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].y = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x = tileCount - 1;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y = tileCount - 1;
    toLoc.x = fromLoc.x;
    toLoc.y = fromLoc.y;
    checkSolved();
  }
}
```

The player needs to click on a tile that is next to the empty space, when they do this, the tile they clicked on moves into the empty space, and the area where that tile was becomes empty. I'm wondering what changes do I need to make to make the tile slide into place, rather than instantly jump into it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Also, why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: You can use css transitions`. Add this css bit to the puzzle piece. `transition: all ease 0.8s;`

Comment: Hi @vihan1086 thanks for your comment, I'm not sure where to enter ``transition: all ease 0.8s;``, feel free to edit the above code to show the correct way.

Comment: @Henry you can place that in your css

Comment: Hi @j08691 thanks for your comment, will post full code soon. I wasn't sure if making the tile slide would require a jQuery animation or if it can be done with solely Javascript.

Comment: It can be done in JS without jQuery but it makes no sense. Today, jQuery is pretty much standard and you'll get cross-browser and more quality that you can't possibly implement yourself in a reasonable amount of time. So the best choice is to use jQuery for production. I would recommend to use plain-JS only if you need to study it or gain true understanding of how jQuery does probably work inside.

Comment: Hi @vihan1086 it doesn't have a css file, it's just a single .js file which contains an ``img.src =`` link which links to an image, which the Javascript then cuts up into pieces to use as tiles. Here's a link to the full code: http://pastebin.com/JuHYmKjG any advice on what to add to make the tiles slide would be great!

Comment: Hi @j08691 the code is quite long so I've uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/JuHYmKjG thanks.

Comment: @Henry If you give all you're elements a class. Let's say piece. Then you can animate them. [Example](http://pastebin.com/bhHmQpyj)

Comment: Hi @vihan1086 thanks so much for your help with this, I've tried to implement both of your methods but I think I'm doing it wrong. I'm not certain where to place your code. This is what I currently have: http://pastebin.com/pPFL6fL5   I've entered your code from lines ``15-24`` I changed "pieces" to "boardParts" as that's what each tile is called in the original code. I'd really appreciate your advice on this, feel free to  make any edits that may work. Thanks so much again!